# Why does Android Wear DataMap not have a putIntArray method?

Tags: java, android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I'm curious why `DataMap` in the Android Wear SDK doesn't have a `putIntArray` method, but instead has a `putIntegerArrayList` method for Integers.

`DataMap` has `putByteArray`, `putFloatArray`, `putLongArray`, `putStringArray`, but not `putIntArray`.

What is the reason for not allowing `int` arrays but requiring an `ArrayList` type instead of integer arrays.

You are allowed to put primitive `int` values in via `putInt`, but if you want to put in an array of them you have to store `Integers` not `int`s as an `ArrayList`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* that is a simple omission on our side; I opened an internal issue to address that; thanks for reporting it.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: So? Any news for this ?

Comment: I had opened an internal issue at the time it was posted but I imagine the engineers haven't gotten around to do it yet.